# Focus on text area after tab in prototype Javascript library

Tags: javascript, focus, prototypejs, dom-events

I am trying to make a text area tab-aware and as a part of it I have written the following Javascript. I am using prototype js library,

```
document.observe("dom:loaded", function (){
    $('tabawaretextarea').observe('keydown',function(e) {
            if(e.keyCode === 9) { // tab was pressed
            $('tabawaretextarea').value = $F('tabawaretextarea')+"\t";
                            $('tabawaretextarea').focus();
            return false;
        }
    })
});
```

As expected, the tabs are getting appended at the end. However, my text area loses the focuse and the HTML element next to the text area is getting focused. I believe the return false should do the magic but it does not.

Apart from this, I also tried setting all elements tabindex to -1, some article said I have to use "autoTab" class and set maxlength for tab to work - I tried doing that, as I am using a spring based `<form:textarea/>` attribute maxlength is not allowed(even otherwise maxlength is not allowed in text areas).

Any suggestions?

Comment: FYI, on windows you can enter a tab character as unicode by typing Alt+9 on the numpad. On linux it's an inelegant Ctrl+Alt+Shift+(U,9). It's not useful for normal folk, I would prefer to see it done your way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`return false;` does nothing in prototype event handlers.  To suppress the default action, use `Event.stop()`.  Also, you'll need to do this on keypress, not keydown:

```
document.observe("dom:loaded", function (){
    $('tabawaretextarea').observe('keypress',function(e) {
        if(e.keyCode === 9) { // tab was pressed
            $('tabawaretextarea').value += "\t";
            e.stop();
        }
    });
});
```

NOTE: This works in FF but this will not work in Chrome and AFAIK there is no workaround.  I've not tested IE, Opera or Safari.

EDIT: 'keydown' does actually work, and works in Chrome and FF.  Again, other browsers not tested, but here is the solution:

```
document.observe("dom:loaded", function (){
    $('tabawaretextarea').observe('keydown',function(e) {
        if(e.keyCode === 9) { // tab was pressed
            $('tabawaretextarea').value += "\t";
            e.stop();
            // note that we don't need to focus() the element as it hasn't lost focus
        }
    });
});
```

[See it on jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/QRLAx/)